# Proof by definition $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n}{n^2+1}=0$

Tags: calculus

$$\Big|\frac{n}{n^2+1}-0\Big|< \frac{n}{n^2}=\frac{1}{n}<\epsilon$$

We will take $N=\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

Is the first inequality sign true?

Comment: Your proof is okay. What else do you want to know?

Comment: In general can I prove the existence of a limit to a bigger expression?

Comment: $\frac{n}{n+1}$ or $\frac{n}{n^{2}+1}$?

Comment: What does it mean by "bigger expression"?

Comment: in this example I have decrease denominator resulting a bigger expression

Comment: Ah ha, a number is bigger than another; it is not that an expression is bigger than another. :)

Comment: @gbox Then I believe your question is "is the first inequality sign true?", right?

Comment: @GudsonChou yes, sorry for being inaccurate but in general may I do it to prove the limit?

Comment: For all $n \geq 1$ we have $n^{2}+1 > n^{2}$; so
$$
\frac{n}{n^{2}+1} < \frac{n}{n^{2}}.
$$

Comment: Hi, there $N=[1/epsilon]+1$ is correct.